# Core Java Array Insertion

Tags: java

I want to insert an elements inside an array. I have one array1 of size 5(where all teh indexs are full).I have created one more array2 of size 6  and inserted all the elemnts of array1 inside array2. Now I want to insert an element in 3rd postion of array2 such that elements present in 3rd position will move to 4th, 4th will move to 5th and 5th will move to 6.

I have developed a program below. But getting string index out of bound exception. Please help me to fix this issue.

Comment: Haha. Hahah. Does it need to be an array? I mean, it's possible. But it's *so much easier* with an ArrayList. (Anyway, if there is an issue with some code, please *post* it. It's likely a trivial off-by-one error but it doesn't do much good to have a guessing party.)

Comment: Include the code you use. I can whip you up an 'insert' method if you want.

Comment: Please update your code.

Comment: A) This isn't a "do my homework" service. B) You didn't post code. C) Don't use an array. (And the two people who upvoted this *please* explain the wisdom behind doing so).

Comment: Use arraylist(mutable array implementation in java). It will solve your problem.

Comment: You should improve your question by adding some code to show what you are trying to do.

Comment: @BrianRoach I guess once everybody who is working with Java is new to Java and looking for answers, altough the question would be better as "best array alternative" it is still valuable.

Answer (score 3):

`System.arraycopy(...)` method is your helper. The rest you will do by yourself.

Answer (score 2):

Sadly array is not the best for this task. I would recommend you to use List (ArrayList) in case if you don't have to bind yourself to arrays. And also you have the method toArray().

Here is a tutorial, but you will find numerous others: http://www.java-samples.com/showtutorial.php?tutorialid=234

Answer (score 0):

I whipped you up something quick.

```
public int[] insert(final int[] array, final int index, final int...nums){
    if(nums.length == 0){
        return array;
    }
    int[] newArray = new int[array.length + nums.length];
    int i = 0;
    for(; i < index; i++){
        newArray[i] = array[i];
    }
    for(int j = 0; j < nums.length; j++){
        newArray[i + j] = nums[j];
    }
    for(; i < array.length; i++){
        newArray[i + nums.length] = array[i];
    }
    return newArray;
}
```

I try to avoid System.arraycopy personally, as here you can see a better flow easier. It is more beneficial if you can see how it works, better than relying on someone else's code.

Answer (score 0):

If You need insertions in the middle of array and change it's size dynamically - it's better to use LinkedList collection.